# How to find polar shape matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, classification, shapes, polar-coordinates, feature-descriptor

I am implementing shape descriptors based classification. I have already implemented convex hull, code chain and fourier and getting successful results. Now I am trying to find [polar shape matrix](http://www.adrianrosebrock.com/journal/tag/polar-shape-matrix). The image below shows an example. If more than half pixels in a sector are of the shape, then I store it as 1, else 0. Now my problem is, how do I scan the sectors? 
[Image](http://www.scribd.com/doc/15071737/38/Polar-model-shape-matrix) shows an example of polar shape coordinates.

Comment: I basically want to know how can I traverse a sector.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the approximative shapes that containing invariant measures. Then you compare by these measures that preserve the same value under geometric deformations.
 For example a triangle you can find a ratio of length as invariant if you don't have complex deformation (Euclidean), or a barycenteric coordinates if you have affine deformation  ([see this paper it may be useful](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/Publications/2004/HF04/coordinates_aicm04.pdf) : ), and a cross ratio could be for the most complex deformation (projectivity), see this pages also for [cross ratio](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/MOHR_TRIGGS/node25.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I'll go through it and get back.